# last column of SPD matrix given it's spectral decomposition

Tags: eigensystem

I'm working on this application where 
I get the spectral decomposition (O,D) of a matrix A for free (A is of full rank) but not A itself, and I need to only recover the last column of A. I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do this than reconstructing the whole of A first?

Comment: What is $D$? Diagonal matrix of eigenvalues?  Do you have the eigenvector matrices for free too?

Comment: @JLC: I edited the question to avoid confusion! Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, for matrices A, B, the last column of matrix product A*B can be written as A*(the last column of B).  You can use this fact to get the last column of the reconstruction using only O(N^2).